# How to chain connect a set of vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I am trying to find a way to use the Fill function on a.. let's say outline of a mesh.
Is there a way to connect the vertices one by one depending on the order I select it in?

I am trying to make an edge loop so I could use the F2 addon to fill the faces in. :)

[image: mesh outline with the vertex loop selected]

Comment: "normally" just select them and press F

Comment: Note that you could have could have just extruded the edges at the end of your mesh to create the new faces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that can save you some time, if there is sufficient matching number of vertices (and proximity) on both sides of where you desire new faces:

1. select the unconnected vertices at one "destination face) away from the existing mesh, using Circle Select, in path order around the circumferance;

[image]

2. select the two vertices that are missing an edge type 'f' (new edge/face from vertices)
3. select two adjacent vertices on the edge of the existing mesh  the vertices on "both sides" of your desired added faces and then use the Select::Edge_Loops.  Do the same for the other recently added edges:

[image]

The result if there is sufficient matches of close proximity:

[image]